# React - Antd - Grid Col Lazyload Overflow

Tags: reactjs, grid, overflow, lazy-loading, antd

I have implemented the following Antd Grid.

```
<Row>
 <Col>
  <DynamicComponentOne />
</Col>
 <Col>
  <DynamicComponentTwo />
</Col>
</Row>
```

As dynamic component widths' are defined after page is loaded. It overflows from the Grid Row.

Answer (score 0):

It was corrected by setting the width property of Row

```
<Row style={{ width: 'fit-content' }}>
<Col>....</Col>
<Col>....</Col>
</Row
```